# UWP app UI not updating from Device Watcher listener

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, listener

How to update UI from bluetooth and BLE Device Watcher Listener Events (add, update, remove) in UWP Application.

Currently I'm using Observable Collection which updates UI when add or update collection object it's working fine but, when I jump on other page and come back Observable Collection won't able to update ui.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are, that you replace the original instance of the `ObservableCollection` with a new one when navigating back to the page, which is [a common mistake](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection.html). But it is impossible to say for sure without seeing your code.